# How can i filter a select based on a string from an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I'm trying to filter the options of a select based on the value of an input, however when filtering occurs, the select becomes empty.

Another problem, my version of jQuery is 1.4.4...

This is my Code:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });

        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().scrollTop(0).data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());
            var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                            $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
            if (selectSingleMatch === true &&
                    $(select).children().length === 1) {
                $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
            }
        });
    });
};
$(function() {
    $('#relProducts').filterByText($('#buscarProdutosSelect'), false);
});
```

---

Edit

A strange thing happened, in fiddle the code works, however when the code is on the aplication it does not work...

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zyx5ojty/

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: Or a snipped... btw, why not use autocomplete for this?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi done, but the code work on the fiddle, but not in the aplication...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki, Maybe there is a conflict

Comment: You may be interested in Chosen : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @JCSama and how can i find the conflict? There is no error in console...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki, is there any link to your application !